# regex.test(): where does it come from?

Tags: javascript

I am curious about the use of the function named *test* (line 3) below:

```
var pattern = /[1-9][1-9]{5}/;
var str = 'this is 248760!';
alert(pattern.test(str));
```

I saw this script in a book and there is no definition of the `test(str)` function.

Why does it alert `true` instead of giving an error?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test

Comment: i think this question needs a better subject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pattern` is a regular expression object

```
/[1-9][1-9]{5}/.test("foo"); // valid javascript
```

A regular expression object provides many member functions such as `test(...)` and  `toString()` to name a few...

```
/[1-9][1-9]{5}/.toString(); // "/[1-9][1-9]{5}/"
```

The `/`'s at the beginning and end are kind of a short hand for the following:

```
new RegExp("[1-9][1-9]{5}"); // /[1-9][1-9]{5}/
```

Answer (score 3):

The `pattern` variable is actually regular expression object (because of the `/` characters before and after), and regular expressions have the member function `test(...)` built in as a part of JavaScript.